# Key Error (0, 0) when trying to use tuple as a dictionary key in Python

Tags: python

I am getting the `Key Error: (0, 0)`. In this part of my code, I am trying to create to dictionary of of block in my grid that has the key (x, y).
Here's my code:

```
self.block_list = {}
for x in range(0, self.width):
    for y in range(0, self.height):
        self.block_list[(x, y)]
```

I don't understand why (0, 0) is not being included in the dictionary.

Comment: What line of code put `(0,0)` into the dictionary?  Your code  (`self.block_list[(x, y)]`) is a reference to an item that must exist.  Where's the code that's supposed to create this item and save it in the dictionary?

Comment: A `dict` is a mapping of (hashable) objects to objects. A `set` is a collection of (hashable) objects. Are you using the former when you want the latter? Why is `block_list` a `dict`?

Answer (score 5):

It's an empty dictionary, and you're trying to *retrieve* the value at that key. If you want to *assign* the value for that key then you  should do so instead.

```
self.block_list[(x, y)] = ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn't *add* to a dictionary, it *looks up a value* from the dictionary. Since the dictionary is empty, you get a `KeyError`.

Assign something to the key:

```
self.block_list = {}
for x in range(0, self.width):
    for y in range(0, self.height):
        self.block_list[(x, y)] = None
```

Now `self.block_list` is initialized with `None` values.